# Enabling CORS by ServiceCollection vs WebApplication

Tags: asp.net, .net, cors, .net-8.0

Documentation of ASP.NET (.NET 8) enabling [CORS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-8.0#cors-with-default-policy-and-middleware) says that developer should add policy using `ServiceCollection` of `WebApplicationBuilder` and then enable CORS using WebApplication like this:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// ...

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddDefaultPolicy(
        policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("http://example.com");
        });
});

var application = builder.Build();

application.UseCors();
```

But `WebApplication` has `UseCors` overload that accepts policy builder. Then CORS could be enabled like this:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// ...

var application = builder.Build();

application.UseCors(
        policy =>
        {
            policy.WithOrigins("http://example.com");
        });
```

I tested both solutions locally and both worked for me the same. Why then documentation says to define CORS on `ServiceCollection`?

Comment: These aren't the same things. `Services.AddCors` only registers the services used by CORS with DI. It's `application.UseCors` that actually adds the CORS middleware to the .NET Core pipeline

Comment: Beyond that, `AddCors` can register multiple named policies. `UseCors` can select one of them by name, or set/override the default policy.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, add this as answer, please